# How do I add STOP Multiple Form Submit with JQuery Validation

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I would like to stop disable submit button once validation is completed and form is submitting so I will not have multiple inserts to DB. I have not updated post with full form validation, because most of you saying that is wrong, but I don't think so.

Here is the submit:

```
<input class="button2" style="border-right:none; font-size:13px;" name="List Item" id="submit" type="submit" value="List Item" />
```

And below jQuery validation:

```
   <script src="http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/additional-methods.js"></script>   

<script>
$( "#UploadForm" ).validate({

  errorLabelContainer: "#messageBox",
  wrapper: "td",

  rules: {  

   <?php if ($type == 'Aution' || $type == 'Both') {  ?> 
    auction_price: {
    required: true,
    number: true,
    min: 1.00
    }, 
    auction_reserve_price: {
    number: true,
    range: [1.00, 500000.00]
    },
    <?php } ?>

    <?php if ($type == 'BuyItNow' || $type == 'Both') {  ?> 
    auction_bin_price: {
    required: true,
    number: true,
    range: [1.00, 500000.00]

    }, <?php } ?>


    Country: {
        required: true
    },

    select3: {
        required: true
    },
    select2: {
        required: true
    },
    auction_postage_type: {
        required: true

    },
        auction_postage_type_price: {
        number: true,
        range: [0.00, 500000.00]
    },

    auction_int_postage_type_price: {
        number: true,
        range: [1.00, 500000.00]
    },

     Europe1: {
        number: true,
        range: [1.00, 500000.00]
    },
     Russia1: {
        number: true,
        range: [1.00, 500000.00]
    },
     NorthAmerica1: {
        number: true,
        range: [1.00, 500000.00]
    },
     Australia1: {
        number: true,
        range: [1.00, 500000.00]
    },
     SouthAmerica1: {
        number: true,
        range: [1.00, 500000.00]
    },
     Africa1: {
        number: true,
        range: [1.00, 500000.00]
    },
     Asia1: {
        number: true,
        range: [1.00, 500000.00]
    },
     MiddleEast1: {
        number: true,
        range: [1.00, 500000.00]
    },


    <?php if ($type == 'BuyItNow') {  ?> 
    auction_item_quantity: {
        required: true,
        digits: true,
        range: [1, 99]
    },
    <?php } ?>

    auction_description: {
    required: true
    },
    auction_int_postage_type: {
    required: true
    },
    listing_type: {
    required: true
    }
  },
  messages: {
    auction_price: "Please Enter Auction Start Price - In Decimal Format, minimum value 1.00",
    auction_reserve_price: "Please Enter Auction Reserve Price - In Decimal Format 0.00",
    auction_bin_price: "Please Enter Buy It Now Price - In Decimal Format, minimum value 1.00",
    select3: "Please Select Main Category",
    select2: "Please Select Sub Category",
    auction_item_quantity: "Please Enter Quentity - min 1 - max 99",
    auction_description: "Please Enter Auction Description -  Min 10, Max 1000 characters",
    listing_type: "Please Select Listing Type",
    auction_postage_type: "Please Select Postage Type",
    auction_int_postage_type_price: "Please Enter International Postage Cost In Decimal Format, minimum value 1.00",
    auction_postage_type_price: "Please Enter Postage Cost In Decimal Format",
    auction_int_postage_type: "Please Select",
    Country: "Please Select Country",

  },
  submitHandler:function(form){
       $('#submit').attr('disable',true).css('pointer-events','none');
  }


});
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `submitHandler` disable the submit button:

```
$("#UploadForm").validate({

   //all your options here

   submitHandler:function(form){
       $('#submit').attr('disabled','disabled');
   }
});
```

`submitHandler` is only called when the form has successfully been validated.  As long as it returns true, the form will submit as normal afterwards.  If you wanted to get more fancy and not disable the submit button, you could have a global variable to remember whether the form has been submitted, and then just return false from this function after the first time.

Working example with submit button being disabled after the first submit: http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/hHAvD/

Comment: this option is doing validation, but not submitting form at all

Comment: I think so your solution will work, just don't know how to do trick to submit it and disable button after. Maybe use that document.getElementById("form").submit();

Comment: tried that solution, doesn't work: submitHandler:function(form){
     
    document.getElementById('submit').disabled = true; 
    document.getElementById("UploadForm").submit();
  }

Comment: You're on the right track, but you don't need to submit the form within the submitHandler - this event is triggered when the form is submitted!  See here - http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/hHAvD/

Comment: Just get rid of the `return false` from my example, that's specific to how jsFiddle works

Answer (score 2):

Simplest method that should work everywhere, obviously you would run your code and re-enable it if necessary:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submitBtn").on("click",function(){
        $(this).attr("disabled","disabled");
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/8Syrh/1/

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem and i came with a simple solution.
from javascript i am sending a flag in cookie for every time submit is clicked, then checking the cookie on the server side, if the cookie is a valid one then performing the respective action other wise redirecting the control to the user.

Note : i m a java developer so i m not uploading the code, but i think this can also be achieved in .net, php and other languages.

Answer (score -1):

I think something like this should work

```
$( "#UploadForm" ).submit(function(){
  //some other code here
  $('#submit').attr('disable',true).css('pointer-events','none');
});
```

There is an attribute "disable" that will typically stop the button from being usable. Pointer events is a newer css variable that can do the same as event.preventDefault();

But there is always preventDefault as well:

```
$( "#UploadForm" ).submit(function(){
  //some other code here
  $('#submit').click(function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Are you using ajax? If so you might want to remove the disable attribute and change pointer-events to auto after the ajax sends its callback.

To clarify on this, the example I give here is **only** to do as the question asked and disable the submit button. Nothing less, nothing more. It can work along side validate without trying to add anything special.

Comment: but I am using validate not submit

Comment: $("#UploadForm").validate({

Comment: I just used that to generalize it. The submit event should fire regardless of validate, you don't need to use it beyond disabling the submit button.