# Disable submit button with submitHandler

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to stop a submit button to be clicked multiple times and upload the same item multiple times to MySQL.

Because the validation doesn't work, I can not press the button submit button at all. Which means I can't test the code.

I am running related post as well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18000943/how-do-i-add-stop-multiple-form-submit-with-jquery-validation), to give you some more information.

#### What I've got so far, using jQuery validation:

```
$("#UploadForm").validate({

errorLabelContainer: "#messageBox",
        wrapper: "td",
        rules: {
            auction_description: {
                required: true
            },
            auction_int_postage_type: {
                required: true
            },
            listing_type: {
                required: true
            }
        }

   //all your options here

   submitHandler:function(form){
       $('#submit').attr('disabled','disabled');
   }
});
```

HTML

```
 <form method="post" name="UploadForm" id="UploadForm"
 action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
 
 
 <input style="text-transform:none;"  type="text" class="button_date" 
 name="auction_bin_price" id="auction_bin_price" value="" size="15" />
 
 <input class="button2" style="border-right:none; font-size:13px;"
 name="List Item" id="submit" type="submit" value="List Item"/>
 
 </form>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TSc8E/47/)** that has a working demo of solution to your problem.

### jQuery 1.6+

To change the `disabled` property you should use the [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop) function.

```
$("#submit").prop('disabled', true);
$("#submit").prop('disabled', false);
```

### jQuery 1.5 and below

The `.prop()` function doesn't exist, but [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr) does similar:

Set the disabled attribute.

```
$("#submit").attr('disabled','disabled');
```

To enable again

```
$("#submit").removeAttr('disabled');
```

### In any version of jQuery

You can always rely on the actual DOM object and is probably a little faster than the other two options if you are only dealing with one element:

```
// assuming an event handler thus 'this'
this.disabled = true;
```

The advantage to using the `.prop()` or `.attr()` methods is that you can set the property for a bunch of selected items.

Comment: I can see it getting disabled, please check this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/TSc8E/36/

Comment: this is sick, once connected to my validation, it's doesn't work :( validation not working and submit button allowing to insert multiple times

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34700/discussion-between-user2511459-and-optimus-prime)

Comment: Why aren't you simply using the `submitHandler` callback?  Putting the _initialization_ method, `.validate()`, inside a `click` handler is not only verbose, it gets called unnecessarily every time the button is clicked.  `.validate()` only needs to be called _once_ on DOM ready.  See:  http://jsfiddle.net/TSc8E/46/

Comment: Yes, please do.  Wrapping `.validate()` inside a `click` handler seems to be the most common misconception about using this plugin.

Comment: @Sparky Sure. Thanks for making this better. I have updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TSc8E/47/) uncommenting the form.submit( ) thing too.

Comment: I just left it commented out to prevent the 404 error and more clearly show the disabled button.  But, yes, unless there is `ajax` in the `submitHandler`, the `form.submit()` is required.